# Shiny: create a reactiveValues from a list of names

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to generate a `reactiveValues` where the variable names are given by a certain list `list_of_names`? These variables could for example store a boolean indicating the state of the corresponding variable.

Imagine I have a list `x`:

```
x <- lapply(LETTERS, function(i) TRUE)
names(x) <- LETTERS
```

Can I generate a `reactiveValues` `rv` from `x` that behaves like `x`?

I haven't been to able to do so, and all I could came up with was something like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("boolean")  
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  nms <- LETTERS[1:10]

  ### lines that I would change
  rv <- reactiveValues(A = TRUE)
  for (n in nms) {rv[[n]] <- TRUE}
  ###

  output$boolean <- renderText(rv[["D"]])
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

It works, but I'm sure there must be a simpler and "cleaner" way to do this, as `x` and `rv` are quite similar. Thanks to anyone that can help me on this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to call your vector as arguments of the function reactiveValues :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("boolean")  
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  x <- as.list(rep(T,10))
  names(x) <- LETTERS[1:10]
  
  # x as arguments of reactiveValues function
  rv <- do.call("reactiveValues",x)
  
  # still works
  output$boolean <- renderText(rv[["D"]])
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**EDIT** : to me, it is not possible to maintain the original order of the vector. An other way is to keep it somewhere else (if possible), then to call it whenever needed :

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("boolean")  
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  x <- as.list(rep(T,10))
  names(x) <- rev(LETTERS[1:10])
  true_order <- levels(factor(names(x),names(x)))
  
  # x as arguments of reactiveValues function
  rv <- do.call("reactiveValues",x)
  
  # still works
  output$boolean <- renderText({
    p <- names(x)
    paste0(p[sapply(true_order,function(x,p){which(p == x)},p=p)], collapse = "-")
  }
  )
}
```

Comment: Oh nice I like that solution. That's what I wanted, a one-liner to get rid of the for loop. Thanks!

Comment: This has been a while since the answer, but is there a way to preserve the order of letters? The current order after `do.call` is ```names(reactiveValuesToList(rv))
 [1] "E" "C" "D" "I" "J" "G" "F" "H" "B" "A"```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there is no elegant way to do so ; it is probably due to the inner functionment of reactiveValues. I'm not sure that the function does have any order property.
My suggestion is to call the original list to reorder the needed list. For example, see the edit

Comment: Corrected the edit !