# How to load reactiveValues from disk without breaking obervers?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, reactive, shiny-reactivity

In order to save the state of a shiny application to the disk I am using the function `reactiveValuesToList()`.

When I want to load the state from the disk I am using `do.call(reactiveValues, ...)` as illustrated in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51170992/shiny-create-a-reactivevalues-from-a-list-of-names).

But after that the `observe`rs are not working anymore...

---

### Reproducible example

```r
library(shiny)
reactiveConsole(T)

r <- reactiveValues()
r$a <- 1
r$b <- 2

observe(cat("State:", r$a, r$b))
#> State: 1 2

savepath <- tempfile()

save_app_state <- function() {
  saveRDS(reactiveValuesToList(r), savepath)
}

load_app_state <- function() {
  state <- readRDS(savepath)
  r <- do.call(reactiveValues, state)
}

save_app_state()

r$b <- 0
#> State: 1 0

load_app_state()

##### EXPECTED #######
#> State: 1 0
## but nothing happens
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new reactiveValues object. Do:

```
load_app_state <- function() {
  state <- readRDS(savepath)
  r$a <- state$a
  r$b <- state$b
}
```

Comment: How to automatize that with a large list of values to read `r$a`, `r$b`,...,`r$z`?